# Issue in rewriting scripts to be vanilla js (not jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

I've been rewriting my Chrome Extension in vanilla code rather than jQuery, and for the most part it's been easy. I have however come across a part that doesn't work as intended.

Original jQuery-based code:

```
$(".content .flair").click(function(){
    //Irelevant code using "this"
});
```

New Vanilla-only code:

```
var flairs = document.querySelectorAll(".content .flair");
for (var i = 0; i < flairs.length; i++){
    flairs[i].addEventListener("click", function(event){
        //Irrelevant code using flairs[i]
    });
}
```

The issue with the vanilla code is that every click on a `.content .flair` element always uses information from the last element in `flairs` (i.e. `flairs[flairs.length - 1]` rather than using `flairs[i]`.

I just can't squash this bug!

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example

Comment: and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm amazed why is this happening? Umm, what about declaring var outside the for loop ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the loop assigning a reference of the last index element to?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487187/why-is-the-loop-assigning-a-reference-of-the-last-index-element-to)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with closures.

See [SO - Closures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example) and [MDN - Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures#Creating_closures_in_loops.3A_A_common_mistake) with thanks to @Arun-P-Johny

Comment: @ArunPJohny Cheers. It's for a chrome extension, so no need for IE support :)

Comment: then go with the second version

Comment: @ArunPJohny Since `flairs` is a `nodeList` and not an `array`, `forEach` isn't an available method, so I'm just using the first version [see MDN NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/NodeList#Why_can't_I_use_forEach_or_map_on_a_NodeList.3F)

Answer (score 0):

A great option for dealing with this is to turn your DOM element list into a proper Array using slice:

```
var buttonElementList = document.querySelectorAll('button');
// not a real array, so .forEach will not work

var buttonElementArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(buttonElementList);
// returns an array, can call .forEach or .map (or use .length)
```