# setTimeout and for

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is as follows.

**script.js**

```
var main = function(){
    for(var j=0; j<10; j++){
        for(var i=0; i<10; i++){
            setTimeout(function(){$('div').append(i*j);}, 1000*j);
        };
    };
};
$(document).ready(main);
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div></div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I want to display

(sec1)00000000000

(sec2)00000000000123456789

(sec3)000000000001234567890246891012141618

......

, but it display

(sec1)100100100100100100100100100100

(sec2)100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100

(sec3)100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100100

......

Why?What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

The `for` loops run to completion scheduling 100 `setTimeout()` calls.  At that point, both `i` and `j` are pointing at the ending value for the `for` loops which is what they will be at when the `setTimeout()` callback gets called..

If you want to use `i` and `j` in the `setTimeout()` callback, you will have to create a closure to caputure their value uniquely for each cycle through the `for` loop.

There are many other answers that illustrate the details of how to do this.  Here are a few:

[Asynchronous Process inside a javascript for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11488014/asynchronous-process-inside-a-javascript-for-loop/11488129#11488129)

[Why is the loop assigning a reference of the last index element to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21487187/why-is-the-loop-assigning-a-reference-of-the-last-index-element-to/21487254#21487254)